# Multiple select tags to filter list in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, select, filter

I am using an onchange function for my select tag to filter a list of items based on the select option value.

The code I have currently have only works for a single select tag but I want it to be able to work for multiple select tags, which would require each select option value to cooperate.

For example, if I have "Departments" and "Locations" as tags for each item in the list and I choose Department -> IT and Location -> New York in the select tags, I only want to see a list of **IT departments in New York**.

I am having a hard time understanding how I would do this properly. I would assume some sort of for loop to get each select tag and then get the value of the current option in each select tag and only show the list items if they meet the select option value criteria.

I would appreciate any help of how I could achieve this!

**HTML:**

```
<select class="filterTags" id="filterDepartment">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>IT</option>
    <option>Marketing</option>
</select>

<select class="filterTags" id="filterLocation">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>New York</option>
    <option>Washington</option>
</select>

<div class="tags-container">
    <div class="tags tags-departments">
        <span class="department tag">IT</span>
        <span class="department tag">Marketing</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tags tags-locations">
        <span class="location tag">New York</span>
        <span class="location tag">Washington</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var selectClass = document.getElementsByClassName("filterTags")
selectClass = selectClass[0]

selectClass.onchange= function() {
    var filterOptions, tags, i, span;
    filterOptions = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
    tags = document.getElementsByClassName("tags-departments")
    span = document.querySelectorAll(".department")
    for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        if (span) {
            if (span[i].innerHTML.indexOf(filterOptions) > -1) {
                span[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = ""
            } else {
                span[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none"
            }
            if(filterOptions == "All") {
                span[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I would suggest the following logic, add a function to the `onchange` event of both selection elements, the function would:

1. Detect the ID of the selection element that triggered the event.
2. Based on the selection element that triggered the change, loop over the corresponding span elements.
3. For each span, based on the selected value in the selection, check if it should be displayed or not.

Here is a fully working code [and a working example with it](http://codepen.io/Alon_A/pen/vyVYaV?editors=1111):

```
//Iterate the selection elements and add the function to the 'change' event
sels = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
 for(i=0; i<sels.length; i++) 
 {
  sels[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
     //get the selection id of the selected that was change - this returns the selection element
     selectionID = this.id;
     if(selectionID === "filterDepartment")
     {
         //the value of the selected department
         var selectedDepartment = document.getElementById("filterDepartment").value
         //we will iterate the departments spans and check their text value agains the selected department value (or if the value is 'All' we dont need to check//
         var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('tags tags-departments')[0].getElementsByTagName('span'); 
         for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
         {
             if(selectedDepartment == "All" || spans[i].innerText == selectedDepartment)
             {
                 spans[i].style.display = "block";
             }
             else
             {
                 spans[i].style.display = "none";
             }
         }
     }

     if(selectionID === "filterLocation")
     {
         var selectedLocation = document.getElementById("filterLocation").value;
         var spans = document.getElementsByClassName('tags tags-locations')[0].getElementsByTagName('span');
         for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
         {
             if(selectedLocation == "All" || spans[i].innerText == selectedLocation)
             {
                spans[i].style.display = "block";
             }
             else
             {
                spans[i].style.display = "none";
             }
         }
     }
  }, false);}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked out nicely! 

Sorry for the late reply, I didn't get around to test it until now! Cheers! :)